# Could not start AVD, VT-X is disabled in bios

Tags: android, windows-10

I'm trying to run an android emulator but I continuously keep running into this problem. I've already enabled VT-X in my bios but I'm still running into this error over and over again. I've read that antivirus can be a problem with it running but I'm sure that's not the case here. I've also updated everything else and I've wiped the data since I've read that it also helps, but nothing still.

When I try opening the emulator in vs code it gives me the error that the emulator did not connect within 60 seconds, so I tried opening it via android studio first and then vs code but it's giving me the avd and VT-X error.

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you sure that you enabled the VT-X from bios? did you save the changes before you exit?

Comment: I'm positive. I did it twice but for some reason it keeps resetting to disabled? Since the second time I tried again I had to enable it once more. I'm positive I've been saving before exiting however

Answer (score 1):

you might need to install intel HAXM (if your processor is Intel) or Hypervisor (if your  processor is AMD).

steps:
Settings -> System settings -> Android SDK

then choose SDK tools from the top

find Intel Emulator Accelerator HAXM or Android Emulator Hypervisor Driver(depending on your processor choose the right one)

check it if it's not checked, click apply then try again it should work

Comment: Do you think it can be that my pc doesn't have the specs to support it?